# Error when trying to request run time permissions

Tags: java, android, permissions, runtime

I'm trying to implement runtime permission request on my app(s); I use the code provided by android developers training [website here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)
Problem is that I can never get to use the checkSelfPermission method to work inside the arguments of the if statement the "Cannot resolve symbole" is always there. But if used to declare a variable, the method works fine.

It's my first time working with requesting android permissions, what am I missing?

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

private void SendCreditSMS() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    else {
        SendSMS("181", "رصيد");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read about how to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then return with your code. Also, what symbol exactly cannot be resolved?

Comment: final private int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

    private void SendCreditSMS() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            SendSMS("181", "رصيد");
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using one of the many permission libraries out there, they make the whole process a lot less painful. I can recommend, for example, [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)